# Undefined Step Definitions Cucumber

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I was doing some re org, and moved around the files where cucumber tests, step definitions, and page objects were located. The tests were running fine before, but now whenever I try to run them I instantly get an undefined steps error. Is there a particular file somewhere that I can update that will allow the step definitions to be found?

Just a little more info - The folder structure is set up like

```
[]tests
     []features
     []step_definitions
     []page_objects
```

Is it because step_definitions and features are in their own directory?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, hopefully this solution will work for anyone else with a similar issue. There is a file, cucumber.conf.js, that contains the info where the step dfinitions are

```
cucumberOpts: {
    format: formatter.getFormatters(),
    require: ['test/e2e/features/**/step_definitions/*.js'],
    strict: true
  }
```

In that require: section you can also place multiple locations if you have multiple dependancies.